# Interpreting the limits when deriving the Marginal density from joint density function

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, density-function

Joint pdf $\displaystyle f(x,y)=\dfrac{1}{2x^2y}$ for $1\leq x <\infty , \dfrac{1}{x}<y<x$

To find marginal pdf of $X$ and $Y$

Now the solution is given as : $\displaystyle f_x(X)=\int\limits_{1/x}^{x}\dfrac{1}{2x^2y}\,dy$

$\displaystyle f_y(Y)=\int\limits_{1/y}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2x^2y}\,dx$

I need help to visualise this space on the $x$-$y$ plane.

I understood the limits of the first marginal pdf : $\dfrac{1}{x}<y<x$

The second marginal pdf seems tricky: The logic given is that the second set of limits can be manipulated from $\dfrac{1}{x}<y<x$ to $x>\dfrac{1}{y}>\dfrac{1}{x}$.

However, it is given that $1\leq x$, so the integral limits starting from $\dfrac{1}{y}$ can end being less than 1 depending on the value of $y$.

The given limits should form an arc shaped area in the $x$-$y$ plane, but the integral seems to take a parabola shaped area.

Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: For $y\leq 1$ the inequality $x\gt 1/y$ is relevent. For $y\gt 1$ the inequality $x\gt y$ is relevent. So if $y\lt 1$, the given marginal pdf is right. For $y\gt 1$, the lower limit of integration changes from $1/y$ to $y$.

Comment: Thanks .. but its still not clear to me .. as $f_x(X)$ in integrated from $\dfrac{1}{x}$ to $x$, y can vary from $\leq 1$ to $>1$, so how do I get $f_y(Y)$ then ? Does this mean the given solution is wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

Support for the joint distribution of $X,Y$ is the shaded region below.

[image]

I think the given solution for $f_Y(y)$ is wrong. The picture makes it clear that $0\lt Y$. So the marginal pdf should be split into two cases:

If $0\lt y\leq 1$:

\begin{eqnarray}
f_Y(y) = \int_{x=1/y}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\;dx
\end{eqnarray}

If $1\lt y$:

\begin{eqnarray}
f_Y(y) = \int_{x=y}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\;dx
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: May I ask, what software did you use to make this figure? Also, if you could prove your code, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @probablyme It's just WolframAlpha with "plot {1/x,x},x=0..4,y=0..4": https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7B1%2Fx,x%7D,x%3D0..4,y%3D0..4 The shading then done using MS Paint.